# Does eating camel's meat break the wudu?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, wudu

In my area, camel's meat is rare. But at the day of Eid, the camel's meat will be imported and I'll be served with that Insha Allah.

I heard a friend saying that eating camel's meat will break wudu.

Is it so?

Is there any hadith available to prove the above statement true?

Comment: Camel's meat was haraam for bani Israel while Allah made it halaal for us... it *does* invalidate the wudu unlike the eating of other animals' meats. Though I recall having read a hadith about this, I do not exactly recall where or its reference.

Comment: As far as I know only the Hanbali sect believe that it breaks the wudu, and none of the other sects believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Eating camel meat invalidates the ablution. This is because of the following [narration](http://sunnah.com/bulugh/1/91) from the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam):

> Narrated Jabir bin Samura (radiallahu anhu): A man asked the Prophet
>   (salallahu alayhi wassalam), “Should I perform ablution after eating
>   mutton?” He replied, “If you wish so”, he then asked, “Should I
>   perform ablution after eating camel meat?” He (salallahu alayhi
>   wassalam) said: “Yes”. [Reported by Muslim].
>
> وَعَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ سَمُرَةَ رَضِيَ اَللَّهُ عَنْهُمَا; { أَنَّ
>   رَجُلاً سَأَلَ اَلنَّبِيَّ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-أَتَوَضَّأُ مِنْ
>   لُحُومِ اَلْغَنَمِ? قَالَ: إِنْ شِئْتَ قَالَ: أَتَوَضَّأُ مِنْ لُحُومِ
>   اَلْإِبِلِ ? قَالَ: نَعَمْ } أَخْرَجَهُ مُسْلِم ٌ (94)‏ .‏