# Is offering Salaah directly after eating non-vegetarian food permissible?

Tags: salat, meat

After eating non-vegetarian food(like, chicken), if I only wash my hands and do not take bath; then is it permissible for me to enter the mosque and pray?

Comment: Why wouldn't that be halal? The principle is that every act is halal unless there is proof to the contrary. If you start checking whether completely neutral things like this are haram, you will find a life of hardship ahead of you. Waswasa can be debilitating, so unless you see an islamic (!) reason to suspect something to be haram, ignore the doubt.

Comment: @G.Bach This isn't a Halal/Haram issue, this is a should/shouldn't question.

Comment: @cerberus23 So it's a "this is halal, but how encouraged/discouraged is it?" question?

Comment: What makes you think one should take a bath after eating meat? What should be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

There's a hadith addressing this:

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:  The Prophet (ﷺ) ate of the meat of a shoulder (by cutting the meat with his teeth), and then got up and offered the prayer without performing the ablution anew. -- Sahih al-Bukhari 5404 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/70/32))

(See also Sunan Abi Dawud 187 ([sunnah.com](http://%20https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/187)).)  So the Prophet made prayer after eating non-vegetarian food.

However, wudu is needed after camel meat; see [Does eating camel's meat break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9039/17163).

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know only when ine eats camel meat should renew their Waddu.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. "AFAIK" is not the kind of Answer we expect here please read [answer] and try to elaborate a good answer by editing this post: Also consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] for more information about our site and the SE model!